# Avalonia OpacityMask with GeometryDrawing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, avaloniaui

I'm trying to convert this code from WPF but DrawingBrush isn't supported. Is there an equivalent way of writing it in Avalonia?

```xml
<Grid.OpacityMask>
    <DrawingBrush>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="{StaticResource Triangle}" />
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</Grid.OpacityMask>
```

This is the closest I could get. It compiles and runs, but doesn't seem to do what I want

```
<Grid.OpacityMask>
    <VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <ContentControl>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="{StaticResource VolumeTriangle}" />
            </ContentControl>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Grid.OpacityMask>
```

EDIT: Here's the Slider template where I'd need to apply the style

```xml
<Style Selector="local|MediaPlayer Slider.volume">
MediaPlayerVolumeBackgroundBrush}" /> -->
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Track Name="PART_Track" Value="{TemplateBinding Value}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb Width="5" Height="15" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Border Background="Black" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.DecreaseButton>
                            <RepeatButton.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Path Data="{TemplateBinding ., Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanToDoubleConverter}, ConverterParameter={TemplateBinding Value}, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Fill"
                                          Stroke="{DynamicResource MediaPlayerVolumeBorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </RepeatButton.Template>
                        </Track.DecreaseButton>
                        <Track.IncreaseButton>
                            <RepeatButton Name="PART_IncreaseButton"
                                          Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Padding="0"
                                          Background="LightGray" />
                        </Track.IncreaseButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's my volume control solution. Now that it works, I might leave a note "if it's not broken, don't touch it". It works fine with Thumb of width=0, which greatly simplifies things.

```cs
public class BoundsToPathDataConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(IList<object?> values, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is null || values[0] is UnsetValueType) { return null; }
        if (values[1] is null || values[1] is UnsetValueType) { return null; }
        var segment = parameter != null ? System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter) : 0;

        var bounds = (Rect)values[0]!;
        var val = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]) / 100;
        var height = bounds.Height;
        var width = bounds.Width;

        var path = segment switch
        {
            0 => new PathSegments() // Decrease button
            {
                Point(0, height),
                Point(width * val, height),
                Point(width * val, height * .9 * (1 - val)),
                Point(0, height * .9),
            },
            1 => new PathSegments() // Increase button, right-aligned
            {
                Point(0, height * .9),
                Point(0, height),
                Point(width - 1, height),
                Point(width - 1, 0),
            },
            _ => null
        };
        return new PathGeometry()
        {
            Figures = new PathFigures()
            {
                new PathFigure()
                {
                    StartPoint = ((LineSegment)path![0]).Point,
                    Segments = path
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private LineSegment Point(double x, double y) => new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(x, y) };
}
```

```xml
<Style Selector="local|MediaPlayer Slider.volume">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Track Name="PART_Track" Value="{TemplateBinding Value}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb Width="0" />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.DecreaseButton>
                            <RepeatButton Name="PART_DecreaseButton"
                                          Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Padding="0">
                                <RepeatButton.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Path Fill="{DynamicResource MediaPlayerVolumeDecreaseBrush}">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoundsToPathDataConverter}" ConverterParameter="0">
                                                        <Binding Path="Bounds" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                                                        <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Slider}" />
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </RepeatButton.Template>
                            </RepeatButton>
                        </Track.DecreaseButton>
                        <Track.IncreaseButton>
                            <RepeatButton Name="PART_IncreaseButton"
                                          Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Padding="0"
                                          Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <RepeatButton.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Path Fill="{DynamicResource MediaPlayerVolumeBackgroundBrush}">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoundsToPathDataConverter}" ConverterParameter="1">
                                                        <Binding Path="Bounds" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                                                        <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Slider}" />
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </RepeatButton.Template>
                            </RepeatButton>
                        </Track.IncreaseButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
                <Path Stroke="{DynamicResource MediaPlayerVolumeBorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoundsToPathDataConverter}" ConverterParameter="0">
                            <Binding Path="Bounds" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                            <Binding>
                                <Binding.Source>
                                    <system:Double>100</system:Double>
                                </Binding.Source>
                            </Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IValueConverter` to calculate the path data, just pass bounds and value as parameters.

The below sample is without taking value into account, but extending this should not be a big problem imo.

```cs
public class BoundsToPathDataConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var bounds = (Rect)value;

        return new PathGeometry()
        {
            Figures = new PathFigures()
            {
                new PathFigure()
                {
                    StartPoint = new Point(),
                    Segments = new PathSegments()
                    {
                        new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(0, bounds.Height) },
                        new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(bounds.Width, bounds.Height) },
                        new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(bounds.Width, 0) },
                        new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(0,bounds.Height - 4) },
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: OK that's part of the answer... now I need to apply that style to `Track.DecreaseButton`. I've updated my post with the template. How can I bind to the container object? `{TemplateBinding .}` isn't it.

Comment: Use Binding to self if you are on the Button,  parent for a child of the button or name to button and reference it by name

Comment: ok working on it, and it's a pain. Drawing the "decrease" part could draw the whole shape, but if I don't draw the "increase" part whose left side slides, I won't be able to click to increase. Plus I'll need to draw a thumb in the middle of the right shape so it can be dragged. Plus binding to ConverterParameter is not currently supported...  `<Path Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Bounds, Converter={StaticResource BoundsToPathDataConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Slider}, Path=Value}}" />`

Comment: OK finally got it working with a MultiValueConverter.. had to draw the surrounding line separately from the left/right contents to avoid some border flickering. Posted the implementation below.

Comment: Although I already solved this, I just saw `Visual.Clip`. Could this have done the job I originally wanted?

Comment: Yes maybe. But it needs a bitmap I think, so the option we used is imo better scaleable. I really think there are many ways. If it was me I think I would have a custom control for it with my own render overload.

Comment: Clip property takes a "Geometry" object, not a Bitmap. Such as, PathGeometry.